# Android: Issues parsing XML

Tags: android, multithreading, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a really basic XML file that looks like this:

```
<xml>
  <customer>
    <CustID>10</CustID>
    <custvar1>10</custvar1>
    <custvar2>10</custvar2>
    <custvar3>10</custvar3>
  </customer>
</xml>
```

I'm not getting any results at all basically. Going off of the last app I did, for whatever reason it doesn't give me any errors. I've spent a good 8 hours on this today, so any help would be appreciated. I'm also not entirely sure of what I'm doing with the parsing, I've got a general understanding, but nothing quite so solid.

I've got it split into two threads, or at least I believe I have. I'm just looking to where I went wrong with all this code. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

I thank everyone in advance for their help!!

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button getData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
    getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {

            background();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}

public class Customer
{
    public final String custID;
    public final String var1;
    public final String var2;
    public final String var3;

    private Customer()
    {
        custID = null;
        var1 = null;
        var2 = null;
        var3 = null;
    }

    private Customer(String custID, String var1, String var2, String var3)
    {
        this.custID = custID;
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
        this.var3 = var3;

    }
}

private Customer readCustomer(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "customer");
    String custID = null;
    String var1 = null;
    String var2 = null;
    String var3 = null;

    while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
    {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("CustID"))
        {
            custID = readCustID(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("custvar1"))
        {
            var1 = readVar1(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("custvar2"))
        {
            var2 = readVar2(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("custvar3"))
        {
            var3 = readVar3(parser);
        } else
        {
            skip(parser);
        }

    }
    return new Customer(custID, var1, var2, var3);
}

private String readCustID(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "CustID");
    final String custID = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "CustID");

    final Handler handler;
    handler = new Handler();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            //Display toast
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID: " + custID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    return custID;
}

private String readVar1(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "CustID");
    String var1 = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "CustID");
    return var1;
}

private String readVar2(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "CustID");
    String var2 = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "CustID");
    return var2;
}

private String readVar3(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "CustID");
    String var3 = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "CustID");
    return var3;
}

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
    {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}

private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0)
    {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            depth --;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            depth++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public class XMLparser
{       
    public Customer parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try
        {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(in, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readXML(parser);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private Customer readXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        Customer custData = new Customer();

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "xml");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();

            //Look for customer tag
            if (name.equals("customer"))
            {
                custData = readCustomer(parser);
            }
            else
            {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }

        return custData;
    }
}

private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    //start the query
    conn.connect();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    return stream;
}

private void background()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            //Delcare handler to allow UI modifications
            final Handler handler;
            handler = new Handler();

            final TextView TextVar1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custvar1);
            final TextView TextVar2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custvar2);
            final TextView TextVar3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custvar3);

            InputStream stream = null;
            String URL = "***removed***";

            final TextView TextError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);

            Customer customer = new Customer(null,null,null,null);
            XMLparser xmlParser = new XMLparser();

            try
            {
                stream = downloadUrl(URL);
                customer = xmlParser.parse(stream);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                TextError.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error));
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                TextError.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error));
            }
            finally
            {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //
                }
            }

            final Customer data = customer;

            handler.post(new Runnable() {                   
                public void run()
                {
                    //Display toast
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    //Set Text Views to show data
                    TextVar1.setText(data.var1);
                    TextVar2.setText(data.var2);
                    TextVar3.setText(data.var3);
                }
            });

        }

    });

}
```

}

Comment: In your `readVar1(..)` method you have `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "CustID");` with the same for `END_TAG` and also the other `readVarX(...)` methods (notice "CustID" instead of "custVar1"). Is that what you want? I'd recommend you single-step this in a debugger though.

Answer (score 0):

At first , the regular format of XML should be like this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <customer>
    <CustID>10</CustID>
    <custvar1>10</custvar1>
    <custvar2>10</custvar2>
    <custvar3>10</custvar3>
  </customer>
```

And then, you have to set the following TO-Do procedures for reading the xml

1. create the file stream
2. create the document instance
3. Parse the file from the source
4. Extract the specific node with conditions
5. read and  traverse all the nodes defined in Step 4.

you better read [This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) for more reference

Answer (score 0):

Hi try for this code surely u will get the output..

```
public class TaplistingParser 
{
    public TaplistingParser()
    {

    }

    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url)
    {
        String xml=null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);
        try 
        {
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpentity=httpresponse.getEntity();
            xml=EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      System.out.println("xml="+xml);
        return xml;
    }

    public Document getDomElement(String xml)
    {
        Document doc=null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setCoalescing(true);
        try 
        {
            DocumentBuilder db= dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is= new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            try {
                doc=db.parse(is);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return doc;

    }

     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
//                   if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
//                   }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```